# Enabling button dynamically in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This might seem a duplicate but I couldn't find an answer or solution for my problem.

I have a screen on my Flutter app where I choose a file from the phone's file system (in Asynchronous way via file_picker).

When I choose a file I'd like to make the 'Next' button enabled.
However, I could not manage to do that.
I tried with a boolean expression and a boolean function but with no success because the build function happens before the user picks a file(By clicking on a button to open the file picker).

I tried several solutions:

`onPressed: upload_flag ? () => myAction() : null,`
but when updating the flag after the file picking, it won't enable it.

This is how the file picking functions and checking functions look:

```
  File _scanned_file = null;

  bool upload_flag = false;

  void isUploaded() {
    if (_scanned_file != null) {
      upload_flag = true;
    }
    else{
    upload_flag = false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> chooseFile() async {
    _scanned_file = await FilePicker.getFile(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'png'],
    );
    isUploaded();
  }
```

I have tried many different methods with no success.

Any tips and help will be super helpful!
Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setState?

```dart
void isUploaded() {
    if (_scanned_file != null) {
        setState(() {
            upload_flag = true;
        });
    } else {
       setState(() {
           upload_flag = false;
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually worked! Well with a minor edit (put the other set state in an else statement)
Can you explain why does it work? does setState refreshes the screen when called?

Comment: setState tell the framework to redraw the widget, it is the fundamental of how Flutter works, read more here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive

Answer (score 1):

```dart
void isUploaded() {
    if (_scanned_file != null) {
        upload_flag = true;
    }
    upload_flag = false;
}
```

In this method, you are always setting `upload_flag` to false even after just setting it to true in case the condition is true. Also, you need to call `setState()` for the change to reflect in the UI. Need to change to..

```
void isUploaded() {
  setState(() {
    if (_scanned_file != null) {
      upload_flag = true;
    } else {
      upload_flag = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You correct haha I forgot to change it after I tried to make the function return the value.